# I cant send lambda log to Zabbix

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zabbix

I cant send lambdas log to Zabbix.

While I recieve zbx_send_response_ext():SUCCEED but zabbix isn't registered value
Here is Zabbix Server Log

```
3122:20200619:090117.042 trapper got '{"request":"sender data","data":[{"host":"ip-10-5-1-56_ip-10-5-1-56","key":"httpd_access_log2","value":"150.31.74.47 - - [18/Jun/2020:17:24:02 +0900] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 403 3839 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36\"","clock":1592557275.064}],"clock":1592557276}'
  3122:20200619:090117.042 In recv_senderhistory()
  3122:20200619:090117.042 In process_client_history_data()
  3122:20200619:090117.042 log_client_timediff(): timestamp from json 1592557276 seconds, delta time from json 1 seconds
  3122:20200619:090117.042 In parse_history_data()`enter code here`
  3122:20200619:090117.042 End of parse_history_data():SUCCEED processed:0/1
  3122:20200619:090117.042 End of process_client_history_data():SUCCEED
  3122:20200619:090117.042 In zbx_send_response_ext()
  3122:20200619:090117.042 zbx_send_response_ext() '{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 0; total: 0; seconds spent: 0.000053"}'
  3122:20200619:090117.042 End of zbx_send_response_ext():SUCCEED
```

I dont kwow why zabbix server return "End of parse_history_data():SUCCEED processed:0/1"
Please tell me!!!

Thank you!

Comment: which versions are involved, sender/server? what is the sender command line? does that Host exists in zabbix, or is it the Name instead? if you are using a 3rd party tool as a sender, does the zabbix_sender work with the same parameters?

Comment: >which versions are involved, sender/server?
zabbix_server (Zabbix) 4.0.17
zabbix_sender (Zabbix) 4.0.17

>what is the sender command line? 
I don't use  the sender command line.Lambda log transfer zabbix by using AWS Kinesis. when i use sender command,it goes well.

>does that Host exists in zabbix, or is it the Name instead?
YES! Host and Key exist in zabbix.